# How can I add the fonts in editor of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for Android Dev ,The system language is 简体中文(Simplified Chinese).

And I use Android Studio,the Source Code Pro Fonts are very good , but it seems not support with Simplified Chinese.And When I enter some Chinese in the editor,it display in Regular script Fonts ,which is so ugly in the code editor.
[image]

And I have try to install some fonts in my system. But I can't find it in the Android Studio Editor Font  but it shown in the Android Studio Default  System Fonts.
[image][image]
So How can I change the fonts of Android Studio's Editor to display Simplified Chinese ? Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Cancel The  "Show only monospaced fonts" In Editor Fonts Setting.

Answer (score 1):

In Editor Font Setting, you should save your scheme first. Then you're able to set you editor font:

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks.I have do that and there are no new fonts in this selection.

Comment: But when I cancel the "Show only monospaced fonts" I seem the new fonts I installed.